# Getting error in Magento 2 API using CURL Request

Tags: curl, magento2

I am working on API getting timeout error, When I am trying to test API from **POSTMAN** its working fine but when i am trying to send it from **Magento** getting error

```
"{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"Failed connect to abc.xyz; Connection timed out\"}"
```

here is the code I am using in Magento

```
    $this->_curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    $this->_curl->addHeader("Content-Length", 200);
    $this->_curl->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200); 
    //Set header auth
    $this->_curl->setCredentials($this->_authUser, $this->_authPass);
    //post method
    $this->_curl->post($this->_spiderApiUrl, $params);

    //response will contain the output of curl request
    echo 'API Response: ';
    echo $response = $this->_curl->getBody();exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rise the timeout?

also try to use the $response = \curl_exec($this->_curl);

Comment: same error with this as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).